# Why do C++ allow constant to be transformed to reference argument in another method?

Tags: c++, reference, pass-by-reference, temporary-objects

```
void outputString(const string &ss) {
    cout << "outputString(const string& ) " + ss << endl;
}

int main(void) {
    outputString("constant tranformed to reference argument");
    //! outputString(new string("abc")); new only return pointer to object
    return 0;
}
```

Since its prohibited to create temporary object reference transforming to methods,this syntax should be useless but even make things more confusing.So why do C++ bother to support this kind of syntax?

**EDIT**:To be honest,I didn't understand your representation.Considering the above example,we would normally use `void outputString(const string ss)` instead of `void outputString(const string &ss)`.I think the normal thing is 'pass by value' methods deal with the constants/variables and 'pass by reference' methods deal with variables only.The only reason we should use `const type-id &` instead of `const type-id` for constants is efficiency because 'pass by reference' methods only take the pointers(addresses) of the primitives constants/objects variables but 'pass by value' methods need to do the copy.

thanks.

Comment: You are completely wrong about pass by value. Pass by const reference is the C++ preferred way of doing things, except for the "built-in" types like int and double.

Comment: If you think pass by value is the norm, I suggest taking a look at the code from any reasonable sized C++ project.

Comment: The only time you should pass a nontrivial object by value is when you want the function to always work on a copy.  Even then, it is usually better to pass by reference and then make a working copy inside the function definition.

Comment: @Mike DeSimone Why is it usually better? If you pass by value the copy may be completely elided by the compiler if it comes from an rvalue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What are your alternatives?

> ```
> void outputString(const string ss);
> ```
>
> That will create a copy of any string passed, even if the type matches exactly: Overhead that's not really needed!
>
> ```
> void outputString(string &ss);
> ```
>
> That will allow changing the passed argument. We don't want to do that, and C++ does not allow us to pass a temporary anymore, to protect us from changing a temporary (where those changes are lost in the next moments anyway).

So, the way you have it fits on two sides: It allows us to pass non-temporary strings without copying them, and it allows us to pass temporary strings. *And* it protects us from trying to change the argument. Seems like a good compromise.

Comment: but for temporary strings,there are no differences.

Comment: @jcyang, that's right. Both the `string const&` and `string const` version will take the temporary string kind of the same way. In the next C++ version, though, the first version will not copy the temporary - which means the copy constructor doesn't need to be accessible anymore. In current C++, both versions need the temporary to be copyable, even if the copy is optimized out.

Answer (score 3):

It is only allowed to create a temporary reference for const parameters. If the parameter was not a const reference then you could alter the data in the method not realising that your reference was to a temporary copy of the data and so it's prohibited.

When it's a const reference though, you can't alter the data so it doesn't matter that it's a reference to a copy and so safe, and therefore allowed as it's useful as your example shows.

Answer (score 2):

Where are you modifying `ss`?

```
cout << "outputString(const string& ) " + ss << endl;
```

This line creates a temporary under the hood ***without*** modifying the `const&` object `ss`.

The compiler will typically do:

```
string tmp = "outputString(const string& ) " + ss;
cout << tmp << endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

You mean, it allows *literals* to be transformed to a const object reference.

This is important. Otherwise you would have to write OutputString(std::string("literal")) and it would be very annoying. One would find himself making separate overloads for a method accepting std::string and char*.

Comment: No, the literal is implicitly casted to a temporary std::string. That temporary is then passed as a const reference.